# Вывод строк из файла в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, вывод, фильтр

Пишу для своих нужд базу данных, которая сохраняет информацию в текстовый файл в формате:

```
01.12.19
Заявка № 12345 - Выполненные работы соответствуют ожиданиям
---

14.12.19
Заявка № 22345 - Выполненные работы завершены не в срок
---
```

Таких записей в файле тысячи. Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы при необходимости можно было выполнить поиск и вывод всех строк содержащих заданное слово и дату, как в примере выше.

Вот пример части моего кода для этого события:

```
w=str(input())
f=open("D:/DataBase/Registry.txt").read()
if w in f:
    print(w)
```

Но естественно выводится только первое искомое слово и то один раз.

Comment: попробуй добавить цикл while i <= f.write(): if w in f: print(w) i = i + 1

Comment: Не совсем понятно - если я ввести только дату, то что должно вывестись? Только дата (если есть) или ещё и строчки, которые к этой дате относятся?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, строчки тоже должны выводиться, до так званого разделителя в виде тире. Но думаю по дате вряд-ли кто-то будет искать, хотя... Кстати пробовал запускать скрипт как написано в предложении, результат не тот что ожидается.

Comment: evik, если под словом предложение вы имеете мой ответ, то скажите что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
w=str(input())
f=open("D:/DataBase/Registry.txt").read()
    while i <= f.write(): # Пока i меньше количества байт в файле
        if w in f:
            print(w)
        i = i + 1
```